Weight paint not working with geometry nodes - Blender 4.3
I'm so confused on this.  Followed all the step from other videos and went back and forth with ChatGBT and it's just not working.
Have a logo mesh, all the normals are good, it's 100% manifold just in case.  I made some snow to put on it which covers everything of course, used weight paint to remove areas and it doesn't work.  It only partially works.   It shows the weight paint is correct, but the geometry is not respecting it.  And for some reason when the geometry nodes are connected, it turns the entire weight paint blue.....even though you can still add/remove the areas it does allow, those remain blue.  I already tried the vertex weight overlays to active or none, nothing happens.
I have 100% of the vertices assigned to the vertex group.
For some reason, it will not remove snow from the front side at all.  If I remove the vertices from the weight paint vertex group, the entire thing is snowy, as it would be, if if I add all the vertex and paint away to remove everything, it will remove the snow everywhere except the front
I figured out a brute force workaround.....but manually selecting areas and making the faces inverted/inside instead of outside and that allowed me to customize the front.   Still clueless why the front is immune to being removed when normals are properly facing out.







Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

So.... where in the nodes are you actually referencing the vertex group? Also, you're connecting Z to the density factor, that is very very probably the reason almost everything is full density for any Z > 1.

The file would be good, because from the screenshots I have no idea how this is supposed to work. You say " the weight paint is correct, but the geometry is not respecting it" - well, why should the geometry respect it? You make no use of it in the nodetree, and if you do in the material shader, you do not show it.

All the geometry turning blue once you connect the geometry nodes is because the ice is covering the original geometry.

Does this work?  First time using it.  This file has certain faces turned inside out though in order to force the snow to not be on them.


I was following some tutorials on youtube, so I have them connected to where they said to.  That's all new to me.  I couldn't find anywhere that explained if weight panting would be any different if using geometry nodes.  Both what I found online and AI all said the same thing, just make sure the weight paint is on the same object and all the vertices assigned.  Which was working, except on the front side.
